# TypeScript Node.js this command undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript

I started writing Ts, but now I'm a novice.

```
  export class CrudController<AddDto extends CoreAddDto>{

   protected readonly addDtotype: new () => AddDto;

    constructor(addDtotype: (new () => AddDto)) {
        this.addDtotype = addDtotype;
      }

    public async add(ctx: any, next: any) {

    /// this undefined !!! ///
      const dto = new this.addDtotype();


     Object.assign(dto, ctx.request.body);

    }
  }

class FooController extends
  CrudController<FooDto> {

  constructor {
    super(FooDto);
  }
}
```

[image]
**Why didn't I understand this command undefined?**

---

this works

```
public add = async (ctx: any, next: any) => { }
```

method works as a property, why ??

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . How do you use the class? What exactly is undefined? 'command' isn't a term, it needs an explanation.

Comment: @estus I tried to explain my problem a little more. Would you please let me know if I'm missing one?

Comment: No, it isn't undefined. The problem may be specific to your IDE, or TS version, or anything else in your environment.

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20AddDto%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20CrudController%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20protected%20readonly%20addDtotype%3A%20new%20()%20%3D%3E%20AddDto%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(addDtotype%3A%20(new%20()%20%3D%3E%20AddDto))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.addDtotype%20%3D%20addDtotype%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20async%20add(ctx%3A%20any%2C%20next%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20dto%20%3D%20new%20this.addDtotype()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A

Comment: It shows correct type for `this.addDtotype`.

Comment: @estus IDE; vs code, ts version; 2.7.2

Comment: Does the project compile without complaining about addDtotype? If it does then the problem is specific to VS Code and should be proceeded from this fact.

Comment: why are you using `new`-keyword here?

Comment: @estus No, Doesn't compiled. :(

Comment: @IhorSakaylyuk I get the same error when I am not using new keyword.

Comment: I'd suggest to update TS. 2.7 is pretty much old.

Comment: @estus I now try.

Comment: @estus I updated the ts version (3.2.4), but this problem not fixed.

Comment: If there's compilation error, it should be listed in the question. Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to replicate the problem. Try to make it *minimal*. Try to replicate it on Stackblitz. If a problem doesn't appear there, post a project on GH. Again, as I showed, there's no problem with this snippet per se, this may be specific to something or your side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a bug, your linter is correct because your `add` method is unbound. Basically there are two types of function declarations in JavaScript, regular function statements and arrow functions, and the primary difference is that regular function statements provide their own definition for `this` within their scope, while arrow functions binds to the current `this` in the scope they are defined.

So when a method is a normal function:

```
add(ctx: any, next: any) {
  const dto = new this.addDtotype();
  Object.assign(dto, ctx.request.body);
}
```

`this` points to `add`, and not to your `CrudController` but when you change it to an arrow:

```
public add = async (ctx: any, next: any) => { }
```

`this` is not overridden, and so it still points to your component. Note that you do not need to do this for built-in methods like `render` or `componentDidMount`, only for methods you define.

So basically anytime you want to use `this` in reference to your component while inside a method, you should define it like `method = () => {}`. If you seriously hate arrow functions, you can also bind methods in the constructor like so:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.add = this.add.bind(this)
  this.method = this.method.bind(this)
}
```

[TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) has a great rule to help prevent making this mistake (it's an easy one to make) called ["no-unbound-method"](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unbound-method/)

Comment: Thanks your answer.